# localhost on Mac m2 not found during automation

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, safari, localhost

I am using Selenium safari driver in python to connect to a web page (via localhost proxy). When I run this script, I get 'Safari Can't Connect to the Server'. However, if I manually type in the url into safari, it is working fine.

The script shows the intended result on Mac M1 and Windows machines

```
username = <>
password = <>
url = "https://localhost:2132"

Options = Options()
Options.headless = True

browser = webdriver.Safari(options=Options)
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(2)

browser.find_element("name", "username").send_keys(username)
time.sleep(2)
browser.find_element("name","password").send_keys(password)
time.sleep(1)

browser.find_element("xpath","//button[@type='submit']").click()
```